# How to use conditional statement in Postman Body section

Tags: json, if-statement, postman

I have a scenario to validate multiple datasets with the same logic. Only change is dataset location.

**Eg:**

Apple, Sony, MI are the datasets, their data is placed in separate folder. If I pass the variable name as Apple, then in postman body part it should check which data to pass.

**Body Section in Postman using JSON**

```
   {
    "if" : { {{Mobile}} : "Apple"},
    "then" : {"location"},
    "else":
    {
     "if" : { {{Mobile}} : "Sony"},
     "then" : {"location"}
    }
  }
```

If I use the above code, I got the response as **Undefined** and **200 OK**

My expected response should be some ID value (eg: 1,2,3 etc.)

Comment: Can you provide exactly the request body, not the code you write? is is something like this `{"Mobile":"Apple","Location":"path\to\folder"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change variable from pre-request, set body as :

```
 {
    "mobile":"{{mobile}}"
    "location":"{{location}}"
  }
```

and in pre-request

```
const mobile = pm.variables.get("mobile")
if(mobile ==="Apple"){
pm.variables.set("location","somelocation1")
}else if ( mobile === "sony"){

pm.variables.set("location","somelocation2")

}
```

Comment: Yes, I achieved this scenario through pre-request section.